# How to get a validation attr from model by property name in asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I use the `validator.GetClientValidationRules()` method that returns validation parameters from the `ModelClientValidationRule` class. And, It works perfectly for all validation attributes, but sadly not in the ASP.Net Core. Is there some public API I could use to get validation parameters from a validation attribute in ASP.Net Core?

My model:

```
public class Movie {
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Release Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Range(1, 100)]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z''-'\s]*$")]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string Rating { get; set; }
}
```

This is my method that generates my client validation rules by the property name of the model:

```
    IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>> GetValidationRulesByPropertyName(string propertyName) {
        IList<IDictionary<string, object>> clientValidationRules = new List<IDictionary<string, object>>();

        ModelMetadata modelMetaData = ModelMetadata.FromStringExpression(propertyName, this.ViewContext.ViewData);
        IEnumerable<ModelValidator> validators = ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.GetValidators(modelMetaData, this.ViewContext);
        foreach(ModelValidator validator in validators) {
            foreach(ModelClientValidationRule rule in validator.GetClientValidationRules()) {
                IDictionary<string, object> clientValidationRule = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                    ["type"] = rule.ValidationType,
                    ["message"] = rule.ErrorMessage
                };
                rule.ValidationParameters.AddTo(clientValidationRule);
                clientValidationRules.Add(clientValidationRule);
            }
        }

        return clientValidationRules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved in the [How to get a validation attr from model by property name?](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5240) on the github.

Answer (score -1):

I am using fluent validation for this. Farely simple to implement: 
https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

example of ViewModel validation:

```
public class PersonalDetailViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonalDetailViewModel>
    {

       public PersonalDetailViewModelValidator()
            {
                RuleFor(p => p.Address).Length(0, 99);
                RuleFor(p => p.ZipCode).Length(0, 10);
                RuleFor(p => p.City).Length(0, 100);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure this library works in asp.net core app? This https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/issues/309 issue is not closed.

Comment: I am using this in production environment with kendo MVVM.